# Стандарты комментирования исходного кода

Tags: python, c, javascript, java, php

Когда сталкиваюсь с opensource-проектами, в исходниках часто вижу комментарии такого типа:

```
/**
 * Set the default fetch mode for this statement
 * @param mixed $mode fetch mode
 * @return CDbCommand
 * @see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.PDOStatement-setFetchMode.php
 * @since 1.1.7
 */
public function setFetchMode($mode)
{
    $params=func_get_args();
    $this->_fetchMode = $params;
    return $this;
}
```

Полный код библиотеки [здесь](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/db/CDbCommand.php#L113).

Многие распространенные IDE этот формат комментирования понимают, и строят на его основе автодополнение кода. Это очень удобно. Да и читабельность кода на высшем уровне.

Вот интересно, что за стандарт такой? Где с ним можно поподробнее познакомиться?

И, если существуют другие стандарты для различных языков, про них тоже было бы интересно узнать.

Comment: странный вопрос от тебя... практически в любой IDE есть параметры настройки code-style, есть группа людей, которые договариваются про стиль или компания, у которой есть свой стиль, они его и продвигают, может есть рекомендации от разработчиков... можно придумать свой или писать как тебе удобнее, а при коммите проекта, например, IDEA будет пушить подогнанный код.

Comment: Gorets, а что странного то? Вижу интересную штуку с потенциально полезными возможностями. Пытаюсь разобраться что это такое и с чем его едят. Я тут недавно узнал про комменты в формате `// TODO:`, которые идеешка автоматически сканирует и выводит в отдельный список. Радовался как ребенок :). Век живи - век учись!

Comment: //FIXME, а в Eclipse еще и такой фокус должен работать... =) да я сам не знаю, уже бы и не должен нечему удивляться... =)

Comment: Вижу в тегах `java`. Конкретно в джаве такие комментарии называются JavaDoc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Причем тут вообще Doxygen? Это называется [Docstring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docstring). В данном примере же приведен [PHPDoc](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc). Почитать документацию можно [тут](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/index.html). IDE понимают только ограниченный набор тегов. Это, как-правило, теги:

- `@deprecated` - помечает класс/метод, как устаревший. В IDE такие методы отображаются перечеркнутые.
- `@method` - какой-либо метод. Соответственно в IDE будет работать автодополнение по этому методу, даже если его не существует. Так же если в качестве возвращаемого типа указан класс, то будет работать автодополнение при цепочке вызовов.
- `@param` - параметр метода/функции. Если в качестве типа параметра указан какой-либо класс, то в методе будет работать автодополнение для этого класса.
- `@property`, `@property-read`, `@property-write` - тоже самое, что и `@method`, только для свойства.
- `@return` - возвращаемый тип. IDE используют для автодополнения при цепочке вызовов.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Упоминание утилиты Doxygen дало точку отсчета для поиска информации по документированию исходников в целом. Но ваш ответ наиболее точно раскрывает суть вопроса.

Comment: > В данном примере же приведен PHPDoc. 

@Ilya\_Pirogov, данный пример очень даже нормально прожуется Doxygen, что подтверждается несколькими вопросами на форуме Yii на тему "а какая же на самом деле используется система генерации документации".

А вот обратное неверно. Всё, что за пределами PHP, phpDocumenter не берет, мало возможностей по генерации диаграмм, мало допустимых выходных форматов.

Можно, конечно, использовать свою утилиту для каждого языка по религиозным соображениям. Мы тоже пробовали, но в итоге остановились на Doxygen для всего, кроме Java - JavaDoc достаточно крут.

Comment: Он может прожеваться хоть хоть самописным велосипедом Васи Пупкина, PHPDoc'ом (кстати, имя производное от духовного наследника JavaDoc) от этого он не не перестанет быть. Соответственно документация по тегам так-же находится на соответствующем сайте. Во всех IDE данные комментарии так же называются PHP Doc'ами.

Comment: > Соответственно документация по тегам так-же находится на соответствующем сайте.

- [Не аргумент.](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/commands.html) Куча генераторов наследует одни и те же команды.

> Во всех IDE данные комментарии так же называются PHP Doc'ами.

- [Внезапно!](http://0lab.ru/netbeansdoxygen.png). Комментарии - это всего лишь разметка. Какую утилиту выбрать - дело разработчика.

Полезные ссылки:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_documentation_generators
- http://technosophos.com/node/279

Answer (score 7):

[doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) — система документирования для C++, C, Java, Objective-C, Python, IDL, Fortran, VHDL, PHP, C#, и, в некоторой степени, D.

Плюсы Doxygen:

- наличие утилит, обрабатывающих исходный код, извлекающих комментарии такого вида и формирующих документацию разработчика;
- формализация комментария — знакомому с разметкой Doxygen очень легко читать комментарии (ясно, где описание функции, где описание параметров, где описание возвращаемого значения и т.п. в отличие от свободного стиля оформления комментария).

Doxygen используется в весьма серьезных проектах:

- [пример использование разметки кода класса QFile из Qt Core (см. определение класса с строки 187)](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/corelib/io/qfile.cpp);
- [пример сгенерированной документации по API для D-BUS](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/index.html).

Comment: точно, забыл про это упомянуть...

Comment: Здорово! Спасибо. Теперь понятно с какого ключевика в гугле стартовать :)

Answer (score 5):

Этот стандарт комментирования в Java называется [JavaDoc](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc).

Напомню - для тех кто не в курсях, Java первый массовый язык программирования, в котором стандарт документирования кода является частью среды разработки.

Comment: Согласен, ноги растут оттуда.

Answer (score 1):

Когда-то javadoc придумала компания Sun для Java.
http://java.sun.com/j2se/javadoc/faq/index.html#howdoiwritecomments
Позже, многие начали приходить к подобным комментариям в других языках. Doxygen использует похожую концепцию